# strophe.flxhr.js - TypeError: this.func.prependArg is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmpp, typeerror, strophe

`strophe.flxhr.js`

```
/* flXHR plugin
**
** This plugin implements cross-domain XmlHttpRequests via an invisible
** Flash plugin.
**
** In order for this to work, the BOSH service *must* serve a
** crossdomain.xml file that allows the client access.
**
** flXHR.js should be loaded before this plugin.
*/

Strophe.addConnectionPlugin('flxhr', {
    init: function () {
        // replace Strophe.Request._newXHR with new flXHR version
        // if flXHR is detected
        if (flensed && flensed.flXHR) {
            Strophe.Request.prototype._newXHR = function () {
                var xhr = new flensed.flXHR({
                    autoUpdatePlayer: true,
                    instancePooling: true,
                    noCacheHeader: false});
                xhr.onreadystatechange = this.func.prependArg(this);

                return xhr;
            };
        } else {
            Strophe.error("flXHR plugin loaded, but flXHR not found." +
                          "  Falling back to native XHR implementation.");
        }
    }
});
```

This is a code provided by a book from which I am trying to learn XMPP programming with JavaScript and jQuery. It also uses `strophe.js` and `flXHR.js`. `strophe.flxhr.js` is used as script file in the main app. But while running the app in my FireFox browser, Web Console is giving me the error `TypeError: this.func.prependArg is not a function`. Also I am using WebStorm IDE and it shows `Unresolved function or method prependArg()`. But according to the book, this should run. What wrong am I doing?

Please Help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, there was a fault with the `strophe.flxhr.js` file. It was a very old version (6 years old). There is a new version of this in github [here](https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins/tree/master/flxhr).
There is a slight change in the code, and this is working. No errors are thrown by the web console. This is the new code:

`strophe.flxhr.js`:

```
/* flXHR plugin
**
** This plugin implements cross-domain XmlHttpRequests via an invisible
** Flash plugin.
**
** In order for this to work, the BOSH service *must* serve a
** crossdomain.xml file that allows the client access.
**
** flXHR.js should be loaded before this plugin.
*/

Strophe.addConnectionPlugin('flxhr', {
    init: function (conn) {
        // replace Strophe.Request._newXHR with new flXHR version
        // if flXHR is detected
        if (flensed && flensed.flXHR) {
            Strophe.Request.prototype._newXHR = function () {
                var xhr = new flensed.flXHR({
                    autoUpdatePlayer: true,
                    instancePooling: true,
                    noCacheHeader: false,
                    onerror: function () {
                        conn._changeConnectStatus(Strophe.Status.CONNFAIL,
                                                  "flXHR connection error");
                        conn._onDisconnectTimeout();
                    }});
                xhr.onreadystatechange = this.func.bind(null, this);

                return xhr;
            };
        } else {
            Strophe.error("flXHR plugin loaded, but flXHR not found." +
                          "  Falling back to native XHR implementation.");
        }
    }
});
```

> EDIT:
>   From the developer of this script, `Jack Moffitt`:
>   "This code no longer works. strophe.flxhr.js just makes some testing easier as it relaxes the CORS requirement by using Flash instead. Most things support CORS natively now, so it is probably not needed anyway. It doesn't provide any APIs or anything that are needed by the example code; it's purely an alternate implementation of XMLHttpRequest. If you can make the  newer version work, then use it.".
>   [Here](https://github.com/metajack/profxmpp/issues/3#event-459241039) is the conversation.